# pseudo:before not taking background property in chrome

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css3pie

The pseudo :before works on Firefox, Safari but not in Chrome.
Its a square box rotated to form a diamond shape. But, using :before the bg is again rotated backwards and given a position fixed. It gives a really nice effect !
Check My Site :
www.wangeltmg.com
When you scroll at first, the background overlaps and creates blurry image to get cleared.. !
All i did is

```
#element3
  {
    width: 1000px;
    height:1000px;
    line-height: 5em;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 0px solid #666;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top:150px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);

    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    left:0; right:0;
    top:10%;
  }

  #element3:before
  {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -10%;
    z-index: 0;
    background: url(../img/custom11.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat fixed; 
    background-size:135% 135%; 
    background-position:140px -315px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
```

Is there anything to work on regarding the compatibility with Chorme ?

I would love to have your answers fellas.

Thanks.

Comment: please provide a self-contained example. linking to websites is not practical (e.g. what if the site goes offline? what if it changes?). embed the markup (HTML) for that CSS snippet, and/or link to a live demo (using e.g. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)).

Comment: why the close vote? this is definitely *on-topic*.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS background is behaving bizarre on chrome because you needed to add:

-webkit-transform CSS 3 transform with prefix for Chrome.

```
.parallax-two #element3 {
    border: 0 solid #666666;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 1000px;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 5em;
    margin: 150px auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 10%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 1000px;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/mmvdz/6
http://fiddle.jshell.net/mmvdz/6/show/

For Firefox, Chrome, Opera, IE etc. it is preferred to add the vendor prefix CSS3 versions as well. It is needed for older versions of Firefox as well for example.

```
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
```

If you use editor like Sublime Text to code manually. You have plugins which add this vendor prefix automatically.
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-automatic-vendor-prefix/

I do see that you have another problem on Chrome. The fixed div has issues with z-index. And it seems it has to do with CSS 3 transform properties for webkit which makes the triangle appear above the fixed div but without the blur effect in Chrome.

```
#home-wrap {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```